# warning message in excel file

Tags: excel, download, asp-classic

I code an asp file to response an excel file using Excel.Application object. I change the content type below.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

When user downloads this file and open it, he get the following message.

> The file format and extension of 'test.xls' don't match. The file
>   could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open
>   it. Do you want to open it anyway?

I don't want to give this message to use. How can I remove this message from excel file.

Comment: Check this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1956449.aspx?Export+excel+Error+asp+net+grid+

Comment: What are you using to generate the Excel file?   Are you sure it actually is Excel and not a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a feature in MS Excel called `Extension Hardening`. There are 2 ways to fix this problem

1. You need to generate proper XLS files that are truly excel files, not HTML Tables saved with XLS extension
2. Each of the client machines need a registry tweak as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx)

Comment: When I disabled 'Extension Hardening' issue was resolved. Though this is just as a work around, still found your suggestion useful.

Comment: @DeepakKumar glad it helped !